# Bash script for loop, for creating Keyvault Secrets from two files

Tags: bash, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I am trying to create a bash script that will enter in multiple new secrets into a Keyvault in azure using a list of keys in one text file and another list for the values. I am a noobie and it may be something super obvious so please be kind.

The script I am trying to use is:

```
#!/bin/bash

key=$1 
value=$2

for ((i=0;i<=${#key[@]};i++)); do
   echo ${key[i]}
   echo ${value[i]}
   #az keyvault secret set --vault-name KeyVaultName --name "${key[i]}" --value "${value[i]}"
done
```

Comment: You can't have arrays in `$1` and `$2`. They're just ordinary strings.

Comment: Where is the script reading from the files?

Comment: You can use `paste file1 file2` to combine the two files side by side, and pipe this to a loop that reads the key and value.

Comment: @Barmar I definitely went with the paste upon further research and it worked great...at first...It seemed to complete the operation once but upon a second run, the script seems to just sit there not doing anything. Idk what the issue is, if it is Ubuntu 20.04 or what, but manual entry of the az keyvault secret set commands still work just fine so I don't think it is a lag issue with the server...
currently using:
#!/bin/bash

key=$1
value=$2

paste $key $value | while read if of; do
  az keyvault secret set --vault-name VaultName --name "$if" --value "$of"
done

Comment: paste $key $value | while read if of; do
  az keyvault secret set --vault-name VaultName --name "$if" --value "$of"
done

Comment: It's hard to tell without formatting, but that looks like it should work. I can't think of a reason why it would work once and fail the next time. Maybe it has something to do with Azure.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't quite figure out why but  I did figure out a workaround. It seems to be an issue, not with azure, but with the paste function. It removes backslashes for some reason, but by doubling up and using "\\" in every instance, I have ensured that the resulting values have the slashes where needed. Really peculiar. I have also adjusted the script to dynamically generate Keyvaults and populate them based on the name of the second input text (the values.txt). I will paste code below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue not with Azure, but with the paste function. It removes backslashes for some reason, but by doubling up and using two `\` in every instance, I have ensured that the resulting values have the slashes where needed.

Running:

```
bash keyvault_creator.sh key.txt vault1.txt
```

Runs:

```
#!/bin/bash

key=$1
value=$2

az keyvault create --location <location> --name "${value%.*}" --resource-group <ResourceGroupName>

paste $key $value | while read if of; do
  echo "$if" "$of"
  az keyvault secret set --vault-name "${value%.*}" --name "$if" --value "$of"
done
```

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds some problems with the code.

Comment: @pjh Yes, that is a good point. Shellcheck throws a weird error, but in similar scripts I found that the issue might be because i did not use the -r flag with the read command which can mangle backslashes